# Search Query for 1 field but search on 3 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I have a Software with a phone book option. It is also possible to conect this phone book to a database.

My Problem is: this phone book can search only on one field in the database but some data on the database have 3 fields as telephone numbers.

Table values could be somthing like this:

select * from table_Phonebook

```
id     |Name        |PhoneNumber1  |PhoneNumber2   |PhoneNumber3
-------------------
 1     |John Wood   |1-200-123450  |1-200-123450   |1-200-333333
 2     |Bill Gates  |1-201-65481   |1-641-88481    |1-201-444444
 3     |Paul Dilon  |1-200-987456  |1-200-456987   |1-200-555555
```

select Name from Phonebook where PhoneNumber1='1-200-123450'
Return value is 'John Wood'

For view I want to have:

select Name from view_Phonebook where PhoneNumber='1-201-444444'

Return value should be 'Bill Gates'

Should I define a view on my database, how?  How could I sove this?

**Edit**

Actually I couldn't write any queries in the phone book. In this phone book I can only define the table/view name and also the field name which contains phone numbers. That means in the phone book I can Only define PhoneNumber1 or PhoneNumber2 or PhoneNumber3 as search field but I want to make it possible to search all of these fields in same time.

Is that possible to create a view from the table_Phonebook which return values in this form:

```
 1     |John Wood   |1-200-123450
 1     |John Wood   |1-200-123450
 1     |John Wood   |1-200-333333
 2     |Bill Gates  |1-201-65481
 2     |Bill Gates  |1-641-88481
 2     |Bill Gates  |1-201-444444
 3     |Paul Dilon  |1-200-987456
 3     |Paul Dilon  |1-200-456987
 3     |Paul Dilon  |1-200-555555
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an [OR](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Somnething like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE PhoneNumber1 = '1-201-444444'
OR PhoneNumber2 = '1-201-444444'
OR PhoneNumber3 = '1-201-444444'
```

Or you could try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE '1-201-444444' IN (PhoneNumber1, PhoneNumber2, PhoneNumber3)
```

This should also allow you to use a parameter rather.

Somthing like

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(50) = '1-201-444444'
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE @Number IN (PhoneNumber1, PhoneNumber2, PhoneNumber3)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please check my edit for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
select Name from view_Phonebook where (PhoneNumber1='1-201-444444' 
or PhoneNumber2='1-201-444444' or PhoneNumber3='1-201-444444')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please check my edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, Name, PhoneNumber1 AS telephone
FROM table_Phonebook
UNION
SELECT id, Name, PhoneNumber2 AS telephone
FROM table_Phonebook
UNION
SELECT id, Name, PhoneNumber3 AS telephone
FROM table_Phonebook
```